# A question about Kleinecke-Shirokov's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ be the space of all bounded linear operators on $\mathcal H.$ For $A, B\in \mathcal B(\mathcal H), $ define the linear map $\tau_{A, B}: \mathcal B(\mathcal H)\to\mathcal B(\mathcal H) $ by
$$\tau_{A, B}(X)=AX-XB,~ X\in \mathcal B(\mathcal H).$$

The famous Kleinecke-Shirokov's theorem says that if $A=B$ and $X\in \ker \tau_{A, A}\cap \text{ran} \tau_{A, A},$ 
then  $X$ is quasinilpotent, that is , the spectral radius $r(X)$ is $0.$

My question is the following:

Is it true for $\tau_{A, B}$ also. If not, is it true if we assume $AB=BA.$

Any help or reference will be appreciated.

I found the following counterexample (after posting this question):

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}$
and $B=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}.$ Then $X=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}$ and also $AX=0.$

Comment: You do not need to SHOUT.

Comment: @XcoderX Sorry for writing in capital letters. I have approved your edit suggestion.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: This is not true. I have found a counterexample which I have edited in my answer.@XcoderX